# Minimum edit distance of two documents

Tags: c++, levenshtein-distance

I know how to get the minimum edit distance of two short strings like 'abcde' and 'abfde',but how to do the MED of two documents or essays with spaces , tabs , enters or even two codes?

For example:

text1:
The computer learns from a huge database of four million videos from volunteers and paid-for market
researchers in various emotional states and the algorithms are constantly updated and tested against real-world
scenarios.
The next stage is to integrate voice analysis and other measures of physical wellbeing such as heart rate and
hand gestures.

and

text2:A computer model has been developed that can predict what word you are thinking of. The model may help to
resolve questions about how the brain processes words and language, and might even lead to techniques for
decoding people’s thoughts.

Researchers led by Tom Mitchell of Carnegie Mellon University in Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania, 'trained' a computer
model to recognize the patterns of brain activity associated with 60 images, each of which represented a
different noun, such as 'celery' or 'aeroplane'.

This is the code I wrote of finding the MED of two strings within 20 characters.

`

```
int med_lev(char S[], char T[]) {
    int dis_lev[20][20];
    int n = strlen(S);
    int m = strlen(T);

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        dis_lev[i][0] = i;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j <= m; j++) {
        dis_lev[0][j] = j;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++) {
            if (S[i - 1] == T[j - 1]) {
                dis_lev[i][j] = dis_lev[i - 1][j - 1];
            }
            else {
                dis_lev[i][j] = min(dis_lev[i - 1][j - 1] + 2, min(dis_lev[i - 1][j] + 1, dis_lev[i][j - 1] + 1));
            }
        }
    }
    return dis_lev[n][m];
}
```

`

I've thought out a method that is delete all spaces , tabs , enters and put every word in a single string but the problem is the string might be too long. Is there a better way?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance#Computation

Comment: How does the definition of MED differ for short strings and long strings/texts?

Comment: The keyword to look for is *space complexity*. You can find algorithmic descriptions of how to reduce it from the wikipedia page.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Your comment with a link gives the impression that you understood the question to ask about the meaning/definition of MED. I do not understand it like that. OP even mentions that they implemented it - for short strings. Is a specific part of what you linked helpful for this question? I admittedly only scanned it extremely briefly, but did not see a discussion of the difference between short strings and long texts.

Comment: @Yunnosch their algorithm has complexity `O(mn)` and therefore gets exponentially slower with longer strings. The more advanced algorithms in the wiki link have complexities that scale better with longer strings. Their implementation is also limited to strings of 20 characters but that'd be easily fixed by dynamically allocating the array (though with `O(mn)` space complexity)

Comment: @AlanBirtles I see. Making it noticably more efficient is of course reducing the difference between short strings and texts. Thanks.